# Correct "Level up" usage

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I am not sure which phrase is more correct

"Level up a total of 5 times. (You level up killing enemies, after you level up, you can choose a perk)"

"Gain a total of {0} levels.(You level up killing enemies, after you level up, you can choose a perk)"

Comment: I think this would be more clear if rephrased: "with each new level..." and "at level six..." in the descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Level up" is fine, but remember that it's *jargon* that many not necessarily be familiar to the general population.  However, it should not be a problem if you're writing instructions to be read by people who play the game.

Otherwise some suggestions:

> You level up *by* killing enemies ...
>
> For every 5 times you level up / For every 5 levels you gain ...